# With draw9patch content pixels do I need to select all pixels or can I specify each end?

Tags: android, nine-patch

I'm using draw9patch to create 9 patches from pngs and when I select the pixels for the content I am finding that I can't just supply each end of the range although in the preview it looks like it is.

[image: 9 patch with content pixels on right and bottom (2 pixels selected for range)]

I'm finding I have to do this instead:

[image: 9 patch with content pixels on right and bottom (all pixels in range selected)]

As you can see the content areas in the previews on the right are the same. Is this just a bug or is there a way to only select the end pixels of the range (especially useful for larger images).

Or maybe I'm doing something wrong here. :)

Thanks for any tips.

Edit:

Here is how it appears - the Button labelled 'Full Patch' has the full length of pixels on the right and bottom and the button labelled Two pixels uses just two pixels on the right and two on the bottom to define the content area.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When defining the content area of a 9 patch the pixels must be continuous.

Functionality Recap: The top and left pixels define where the image stretches, the bottom and right pixels define content.

Comment: To iterate a bit further, you must fill inall of the pixels between to properly define content. Otherwise you'll get an error when you build. It would be nice if we could just define the endpoints but alas it is not possible at this time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Just wondering, why does the preview show it working? Also I'm not getting any build errors.